# Стратегия сортировки в базе

Tags: база-данных, сортировка, mysql

Идея такова что каждый пользователь может создавать свой пост

Созданный пост считается главным и его может изменять только создатель

а дальше любой другой пользователь может изменять созданный ранее пост создателем

в итоге измененный пост не заменяет созданный пост создателем а добавляется ниже как исправление к главному посту

```
- главный пост 1
|
 - исправление 1
|
 - исправление 2
|
 - исправление 3
```

в отличии от википедии тут используется обычный редактор ббкод

в базе все хранится довольно просто

есть таблица с полем id и полем to_id

если to_id равен 0 то это главный пост, если там стоит число то это число id главного поста на который ссылается данный пост

вопрос в следующем

создатель главного поста должен иметь возможность выбирать главный пост из исправлений

т.е. допустим было так

```
- главный пост 1
|
 - исправление 1
|
 - исправление 2
|
 - исправление 3
```

а стало так

```
- исправление 2
|
 - исправление 1
|
 - главный пост 1
|
 - исправление 3
```

т.е. создатель выбрал главным постом исправление 2 и теперь на исправление 2 должны ссылаться исправление 1, главный пост 1, исправление 3

как делается такая сортировка в базе?

вот таблица

```
CREATE TABLE `blog` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`title` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`message` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`to_id` INT NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

так находится главная статья под номером 5

```
SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE `to_id`=0 AND `id`=5;
```

а дальше идет отображение других статей исправлений к статье 5

```
SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE `to_id`=5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например заведите поле `IS_CURRENTLY_MAIN`, и включите его в сортировку.

Я бы поменял `to_id` на `original_id`, тогда у всех вариантов статьи одинаковый `original_id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE blog set to_id=$newid where to_id=$oldid;
UPDATE blog set to_id=0 where to_id=id;
```